# How to calculate next birthday in months and days and upcoming birthdays

Tags: android

I am beginner in android studio and trying to make an app of Age Calculator but i do not understand that how i calculate the next birthday from today date. I tried so many code and function but with those functions and codes my app did automatically close after i running the application.
I share the code please help me to fix that.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Inatialized the code for the navigation bar menu
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggal;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    // Inatialized the  Code for the calendar
    ImageButton btnCelandar1;
    ImageButton btnCelandar2;
    int year_x, month_x, day_x;
    static final int DIALOD_ID = 0, DIALOG_ID = 1;
    EditText etYeay, etMonth, etDay;
    int year_y, month_y = 12, day_y = 31;
    int dayOf_Week;

    ////// User Input For Date Section ////////////
    EditText uiDay, uiMonth, uiYear;
///////// Day View Inatializer For Current and User Input ////////

    TextView dayView, userInputDayView;
    //////////////************ Code for Button To calculate the age******/////////
    TextView tvYearAge, tvMonthAge, tvDaysAge;
    TextView tvBirthMonth, tvBirthDays;
    TextView tvExtraYear, tvExtraMonth, tvExtraWeeks, tvExtraDays, tvExtraHours, tvExtraMinutes, tvExtraSeconds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //initalized the paremeters
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mToggal = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        //staring up the navigation menur
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggal);
        mToggal.syncState();
        //show up the botton
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       // fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new SettingsFragment());
      //  fragmentTransaction.commit();
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Fragment");
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.settings:
                        Intent iSetting = new Intent(MainActivity.this , SettingActivity.class);
                        startActivity(iSetting);
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.about:
                        Intent iAbout = new Intent(MainActivity.this , AboutActivity.class);
                        startActivity(iAbout);
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;




                }






                return true;
            }
        });


        /// Coding for the Calendar Button start hear

        shoDialogOnButtonClick();

////////////////  Path For The Initializer Day View///////////
        dayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_day_view);
        userInputDayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userInput_DayView);

/// coding for the textview on edit text
        etYeay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_year_view);
        etMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_month_view);
        etDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_day_view);
        //***///




        ///////Inatialized the variable Of user input EditText//////////////////////////

        uiYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etYear_By_user);
        uiMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMonth_By_User);
        uiDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDay_By_User);
/////**********  Current Date Method For Calendar 1*******/////////
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year_x = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month_x = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day_x = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        dayOf_Week = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String weekday = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays()[dayOf_Week];
        dayView.setText("" + weekday);
        etYeay.setText("" + year_x);
        etMonth.setText("" + (month_x + 1));
        etDay.setText("" + day_x);

        /////////*************** Current Date Method For The Calendar 2 *******/////////////
        final Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        year_y = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month_y = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day_y = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        ///////////********* Initialized the path of resulting Factor*******//////////
        tvYearAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_age_year);
        tvMonthAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_age_months);
        tvDaysAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resuls_age_days);

        tvBirthMonth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next_birthday_months);
        tvBirthDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next_birthday_days);

        tvExtraYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_Extra_Years);
        tvExtraMonth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_Extra_Months);
        tvExtraWeeks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_Extra_Weeks);
        tvExtraDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_Extra_days);
        tvExtraHours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_Extra_Hours);
        ////////##*******##////////////////





    }


    public void CalculateAge(View view) {
        String currentyearET = etYeay.getText().toString();
        String userInputyearET = uiYear.getText().toString();
        String currentMonthET = etMonth.getText().toString();
        String userInputMonthET = uiMonth.getText().toString();
        String currentDayET = etDay.getText().toString();
        String userInputDayET = uiDay.getText().toString();
        ///////////////////////***********//////////////////

        int currentAgeInYear = Integer.parseInt(currentyearET) - Integer.parseInt(userInputyearET);
        int currentAgeInMonth = Integer.parseInt(currentMonthET) - Integer.parseInt(userInputMonthET);
        int currentAgeInDays = Integer.parseInt(currentDayET) - Integer.parseInt(userInputDayET);
        /////////////////*********//////////////
        tvYearAge.setText("" + currentAgeInYear);
        tvMonthAge.setText("" + currentAgeInMonth);
        tvDaysAge.setText("" + currentAgeInDays);
        /////////////////////////**********Code For Next Birth Day ************///////////////////////////






        /////////////*************//////////////////////////***///





        int extraAgeInMonths = (currentAgeInYear*12)+currentAgeInMonth;
        int extraAgeInWeeks = (int) (extraAgeInMonths * 4.35)+(currentAgeInDays / 7);
        int extraAgeInDays = (int) ((currentAgeInYear*365.25)+(currentAgeInMonth * 30.45)+currentAgeInDays);
        int extraAgeInHours = (extraAgeInDays)* 24;

        tvExtraYear.setText(""+currentAgeInYear);
        tvExtraMonth.setText(""+extraAgeInMonths);
        tvExtraWeeks.setText(""+extraAgeInWeeks);
        tvExtraDays.setText(""+extraAgeInDays);
        tvExtraHours.setText(""+extraAgeInHours);


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look [JODA/TIME lib](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) it will give you all date format and from/to date.

Happy coding!!